# static_cast vs GetBuffer(0) in casting CString to an LPCWSTR pointer

Tags: c++, casting

There are two ways to convert a `CString` to an `LPCWSTR` pointer. Usually, I use the `static_cast` method. But recently I have realized `GetBuffer()` can be used with the argument `0`. So I think `GetBuffer()` is good for more clean code, because `static_cast` has an ugly syntax though it looks more `C++`.

What are the pros and cons of each way, and what should I use in C++?

```
#include <atlstr.h>  

int main() {
    CString aCString = CString(_T("A string")); 
    _tprintf(_T("%s"), aCString.GetBuffer(0)); //methond -1
    _tprintf(_T("%s"), static_cast<LPCWSTR>(aCString)); //methond -2
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There is no essential difference between the 2 forms.
When running, the GetBuffer() method should return some internal buffer, while the static_cast should invoke the convert operator like below.

```
operator char* () {return _internalBuffer;}
```

it's personal preference which one you like to use.

Comment: My personal preference is the `static_cast`, which is ugly, but _very_ clear as to exactly what you're doing and why.  `GetBuffer` isn't idiomatic, and worse, returns a pointer to mutable data, so I have to wonder if the data is being modified somewhere.